# Decoding a UTF-8 image (string) via JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, utf-8, decode

I have an Angular (1.x) based application that calls a Web API to get customer data. One of the properties on the customer object is their image. When I receive the object, the image data is UTF-8 encoded.

Just to be more clear, the C# based API is doing this:

```
customer.image = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Image);
```

So the image is being converted into a string which is UTF-8 encoded.

On the client side, I am simply binding the customer.image data to an

```
 <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{customer.image}}" ... >
```

This is working just fine in other parts of my application, but the other images aren't being encoded first. This one is.

I've been searching and searching for a way to decode a UTF-8 encoded string in JS, but EVERY answer I've come across seems to work on some variation of decodeURIComponent(). That's not working for me because the string in question is NOT a URI. (I get an invalid URI error).

How can I decode this data using either JS, JQuery or Angular? Seems like it should be simple, but maybe I'm just using the wrong terms...

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is just a character encoding that can handle special characters like the danish ones: "æøå". The first part of UTF-8 though is the ASCII-characters to ensure compatibility with ASCII encoded content (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The Base64 encoding is a an encoding of binary data as ASCII text (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

This basically means that if your Base64 data is encoded correctly then it will be identical no matter if it is UTF-encoded or not. So in short terms your issues should not lie in the encoding.

So to resolve your issue I'd look into if the image data is actually correctly encoded as Base64, most likely you're betting binary data rather than the expected Base64, and in that case what you want is to Base64 encode the data.

As a side note, a recommendation is to ensure that everything that is text/strings that you use is UTF-8 encoded. Make sure that your html, js etc. files are UTF-8, ensure the database is and ensure that you get the meta html tag telling the encoding there. Having everything as UTF-8 will make your life much easier, especially if you run into special characters.